# Take a look at this visualization of tenses

Tags: tense

I saw a visualization of tenses in google.
But I fount some differences from what I have in mind.
How about you? Is this correct?[image]

Comment: Origin: [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/11482). You may want to read the original question in detail. It's quite an interesting thread.

Comment: That chart is of very limited value. I would throw it away. It makes little sense and does not begin to illustrate how tenses are used. It also contains wrong information. Just one example: *I have been eating* can go right up to the present moment.

Comment: I think learners would be totally confused. There is no logic in the arrangement of tenses and some tenses, eg present perfect, have several uses.

Answer (score -1):

**I had eaten** :
"Why didn't you have any pizza yesterday?"
"I had (already) eaten."

**I will have eaten** :
"I'll be back in two hours." 
"I will have eaten by then."

**I will be eating**:
"What are you going to do if the world ends?"
"I will be eating."

**I will have been eating**:
"What if you die of starvation three years from now?"
"That's impossible; I will have been eating."

**I have been eating**:
"Did you put on some weight?"
"Yes, I have been eating a lot."

**I have eaten**:
"Are you hungry?"
"Oh no, I have eaten."

**I am eating**:
"What are you doing, hiding in the corner?"
"Shhh! I am eating."

**I am eating**:
"You will never change your eating habits."
"I swear! You walk in on me 10 years from now, and voila! I am eating."

**I was eating**:
"Why'd you get mad at her?"
"She tried to disturb me while I was eating"

**I will eat**:
"I will eat to my heart's desire."

**I ate**:
"I ate too much food at Grandma's."

**I eat**:
"I love Tome Horton's so I eat their donuts every day."

Comment: Why did you post this? It is about as useless as the chart is.